# Xamarin Native DLL not included in .APK

Tags: c#, android, dll, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a xamarin project that relies on a native dll.

When I´m using "Use shared runtime" my native (C) dll is included in the APK and everything works as expected.

But now i was preparing to package up my projects for a few friends to test it and hence I disabled "Use shared runtime". Now if I examine the .APK-file the native dll isnt included.

Is it something more i have to do when not using a shared runtime?

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little old but I just had the same problem so I hope it will help someone.

When "Use Shared runtime" is ticked, every target is included in the packaging (for example in debug mode) but in release mode or if you untick "Use Shared runtime" only the default target is packaged.

You then have to go to 
**Project Properties -> Android Options -> Advanced**  and choose your targets.

Another option is to modify you csproj and add or modify this line in the configuration you want to modify :

```
<AndroidSupportedAbis>armeabi,armeabi-v7a</AndroidSupportedAbis>
```

@Gaurav : thanks for the useful links.

Answer (score 0):

The way to disable the shared Runtime usage is

```
    <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>False</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
```

I suppose you are doing it this way, correctly.

The building process is well explained here 
http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/build_process/

and also preparing an app for release is here:
http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/

Hope it works out correctly. Cheers

Comment: AndroidUseSharedRuntime is set too false, but the question is, why does the native library stop being packaged with this setting.